# Alphabetical sorting in Nemo: what causes Foo to be sorted before bar?

Tags: sorting, locale, linux-mint

I have two computers - a laptop and a desktop - both running Linux Mint 19 Tara. Both have the same locale settings (shown below). Both are running Nemo 3.8.6 for file browsing.

On the laptop,  Nemo sorts *bar* before *Foo* as it should.  On the desktop, however,  Nemo sorts *Foo* before *bar*;  in general,  it sorts all uppercase file and folder names before lowercase file and folder names.

What could cause this behavior?  How can I get correct alphabetical sorting on my desktop too?

Here are the contents of my `/etc/default/locale` file:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_BE.UTF-8"
```

Comment: I think this belongs on the same forum (Unix/Linux SE) as you posted the answer for.  I have flagged this as off-topic.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the multiple subforums of StackExchange;  I only knew StackOverflow.  Is there a way to move questions to another forum?

Comment: It seems that only soemone with at least 3000 reputation can move questions; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119466/can-i-manually-move-question-to-another-community  I can't do it.  Someone?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the environment variables in /etc/default/locale were overwritten by values in ~/.pam_environment on the desktop; this file was not present on the laptop.  The solution is simple: remove ~/.pam_environment.

I did not knowingly create the .pam_environment file, and in fact I did not even know what it was.  For those interested, here is some background:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables